# ReturnUrl not working when using MapPageRoute in webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I have an existing Web application that was developed in ASP.NET 4.5 and ASP.net Identity 2.0. And i have setting for router in RouteConfig.cs like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
   settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
   routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
   routes.MapPageRoute("manage-user-acc", "manage-user-acc", "~/Account/Manage.aspx", true);
}
```

the manage.aspx page is must login to view this. When application run, i type url in address bar like this:

```
http://localhost:64296/manage-user-acc
```

the returnUrl is not working, and the error is

> An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this
>   request. You might not have permission to view the requested
>   resources.

but when i type url like this in address bar

```
http://localhost:64296/Account/Manage
```

the returnUrl is working and return to login page like this:

```
http://localhost:64296/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Faccount%2Fmanage
```

So can any one help me to find out where I am doing mistake. OR how can I debug all the process

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug. You can get round it by authenticating the route instead of the physical page. Remove the boolean in your call to MapPageRoute

```
routes.MapPageRoute("manage-user-acc", "manage-user-acc", "~/Account/Manage.aspx");
```

And deny unauthenticated access to the route in the root Web.config

```
<location path="manage-user-acc">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```